# JSON Parser Skipping Nodes?

Tags: android, json, parsing, google-maps

I made a simple JSON parser using [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).  All I want to do is parse the name and lat/lng of businesses with the Google maps api, but I cant seem to get it to parse correctly.

**Example of JSON results:**

```
"results" : [
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 41.8881090,
           "lng" : -87.6308430
        }
     },
     "name" : "American Bar Association",
  },
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 41.8721230,
           "lng" : -87.6294680
        }
     },
     "name" : "Bar Louie",
   
  } ], "status" : "OK"}
```

I took out some of the other details Im not interested in to shorten the example, but here's my code:

```
            JSONParser jParse = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject json = jParse.getJSON(url);
    
            try
            {   
                JSONArray contacts = json.getJSONArray("results"); //Parent Node
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)//Loop through first 5 results results            
                {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    name = c.getString("name");//Gets name field 
                    
                    //get lat from location which is a sub object of geometry                       
                    lat = Float.valueOf (contacts.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat")); 
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

When I run it I get the first result just fine, I get the correct Name and Latitude but instead of moving to the second result it moves to the last result of i and prints its for the rest of the loop.  Hard to explain, what I mean is if I loop through 5 results I get:

- Loop 1 Output: Result#1 //This is good
- Loop 2 Output: Results#5 //Somehow we skip to result #5 instead of getting #2
- Loop 3 Output: Results#5 //Now it just keeps printing #5 each time through the rest of the loop
- Loop 4 Output: Results#5
- Loop 5 Output: Results#5

I have no idea how its just ignoring the for loop and getting to the last result? Im printing the result with just a Toast message which I left out for a shorter snippet.

(I will note I am running this through a separate thread and using a handler to display the Toast message, if that matters)

I'm really not that great in Java and the it's the first time I've worked with JSON so spare any stupidity I may have said.  Any help is much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up answering my own problem.  I think it was because I re-used the name variable each time through the loop and by the time the handler kicked in and finished displayed the first message the loop had already finished and assigned name the last value.  So when the other 4 handler requests finally got executed it just printed the same value 4 times.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can not understand your five loop because as you said it should be only three loops. Once when I work with a JSON file I had a similar problem. I recommend you to print the real number of object that you have after

```
JSONArray contacts = json.getJSONArray("results");
```

My problem was that I thought I had the elements I wanted in the array (contacts - to be populate with 3 objects) but actually I was having some thing different (for example geometry objects)

In the languages I had work with JSON the result is a dictionary so maybe you should not concat getJSONObject

```
contacts.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat")
```

Comment: I changed the code. The 5 loop was just an example I should of used 5 in code loop too. Sorry.

Comment: You should use contacts.lenght or something like that, avoid hard coding

Comment: I will use .length() I just want it to loop through only 5 for testing purposes.  Unfortunately I still haven't figured out whats causing this problem.